# Send UDP Data from Python to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, server, client

How do I retrieve data fro this Python Server in Javacript. The end goal is to be able to use Python variables to Control Javascript variables. I've scoured everywhere for hints on how to work with sockets and javascript but they only dive into sending data whereas I'm wanting to receive data.

Thanks in Advance! :)

Python Server Code:

```
import socket
UDP_IP = socket.gethostname()
UDP_PORT = 5005
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

print ("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
print("IP Address is",ip_address)
print ("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)
print ("message:", MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,  # Internet
                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # UDP

#sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8"), (ip_address, UDP_PORT))
```

JAVASCRIPT CLIENT:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5005');
```

Comment: Instead of doing ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), please write ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(""), is better practice. If your intention is to have control over python variables to use in your js, a better option would be the flask rest api of python.

Answer (score 0):

**Best option should be flask**

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
   data = {'username': 'Pang', 'site': 'stackoverflow.com'}
   return render_template('settings.html', data=data)
```

In the above code you specify the route and the data you want to send, previously processed in a python variable.

**In your js:**

```
function myFunc(vars) {
return vars
```

}

In this way you should be able to view your values and use them

**In your html**

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" {{ url_for('static', filename='app.js')}}></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        myVar = myFunc({{vars|tojsenter code hereon}})
     </script>
</head>
```

In the above code you store your data reciebed in **MyVar**, you can omit the json parsing.